# Vue and Rainyday.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I tried to find the way to use Vue and [rainyday.js](https://maroslaw.github.io/rainyday.js/) but I couldn't find anything related. How can I implement rainyday.js with Vue?

```
<body onload="run();">
    <img id="background" alt="background" src="" />
</body>
<script src="./js/rainyday.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function run() {
        var image = document.getElementById('background');
        image.onload = function () {
            var engine = new RainyDay({
                image: this
            });
            engine.rain([
                [1, 2, 8000]
            ]);
            engine.rain([
                [3, 3, 0.88],
                [5, 5, 0.9],
                [6, 2, 1]
            ], 100);
        };
        image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
        image.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/N7ETzFO.jpg';
    }
</script>
```

I modified `run` function into `mounted` but it doesn't work

Comment: I think something like a [custom directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) would work for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried below approach and it works.

Download rainyday.js library [from this path](https://github.com/mubaidr/rainyday.js) . Import `rainyday.js` via `<script>` in your index.html

[image]

This makes `RainyDay class` available in global scope. Now you can use `RainyDay class` in any of the vue components

**`Vue component (App.vue for example)`**

[image]